# Javascript Promise not working as expected

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm calling two javascript functions that return json data from a Python Flask website and processes it. One generates a table. The other updates a [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) table. The two calls hit the Flask server at the same time. This causes the Flask server to crash. I am using the default Flask site. I believe moving to a Production Server may solve this issue. I am working on this too.

Also, I'm not a javascript guy.

I've started using Promises to cascade when the calls are made. I even have a function to just kill a few seconds.

```
    //Update Site components with updated timeframe
    function updateLogTimeFrame(timeframe){

        //Clear table div - id="report-table"
        $("#report-table").html("");

        var handleAllPromises = Promise.all([promisedReportVar(timeframe), promiseTRSANSG(3), promisedTableVar(timeframe)]);
        handleAllPromises.then(function(values) {
            console.timeEnd("Promise.All");
            console.log("All the promises are resolved", values);
        });
            handleAllPromises.catch(function(reason) {
            console.log("One of the promises failed with the following reason", reason);
        });
    }

    var promiseTRSANSG = (promiseThatResolvesAfterNSecondsGenerator = function(n = 0) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            console.log('Waiting...')
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve({
                    resolvedAfterNSeconds: n
                });
            }, n * 1000);
        });
    });

    var promisedReportVar = (completedReportDiv = function(timeframe) {
        new Promise( function( resolve, reject){
            console.log('Running Report');
            //Update Report - Returns true
            var reportLink = "http://10.58.110.67:5000/getReport/" + timeframe
            completedVar = updateReport(reportLink);
            resolve(completedVar)
        });
    });

    var promisedTableVar = (completedTableDiv = function(timeframe) {
        new Promise( function( resolve, reject){
            console.log('Updating Table');
            //Update Table - Updates table (Tabulator)
            var dataLink = "http://10.58.110.67:5000/showLogs/" + timeframe
            table.setData(dataLink);
            resolve();
        });
    });
```

I can run either the promiseReportVar **or** promiseTableVar and the code works fine. My guess is I'm not using Promises correctly. If I look at the Waterfall on the browser, I see the two json requests (happening in updateReport & table.setData functions) happening within 2 milliseconds of each other. So it's not waiting for one function to finish before calling the other.

Comment: `Promise.all` is designed to do all at the same time,.  Also don't forget to return a promise.. eg.. `return new Promise(` not just `new Promise`

Comment: Thanks. Still having the same issue. Looking at the waterfall on the browser, I see the two json calls are called within 5 milliseconds of each other.